# PL PS communication on the zynq board

Tags: simulation, fpga, xilinx, vivado

I am working on an application that turns on a Zynq board. 
I develop the C code that should runs on the ARM host and implement and synthesized the code for the PL. I have data transfer between the PL and the PS.
But, I don’t have the board.  And  I want to test my programs and to evaluate my system (resources, throughput and latency, …).
Is there any way to have this? Any  simulator? How could I see the value of the data that transit between the PL and the PS. 
I only have the vivado environment with sdk.

Thanks

Comment: is the BFM helpful? Let's share our knowledge :)

Comment: Dear Sophie, mark the answer as accepted if you agree: there is a little tic that will become "green"

Answer (score 0):

I want to say that I didn't try it yet, but the answer can be in using [AXI Bus Functional Model (BFM)](https://www.xilinx.com/products/intellectual-property/do-axi-bfm.html):

### **Xilinx provides AXI BFM to verify functionality of AXI masters and AXI slaves with AXI3, AXI4, AXI4-Lite, and AXI4-Stream interface**

The AXI Bus Functional Models (BFMs), developed for Xilinx by Cadence Design Systems, support ***the simulation of customer-designed AXI-based IP***. AXI BFMs support all versions of AXI (AXI3, AXI4, AXI4-Lite and AXI4-Stream). The BFMs are delivered as encrypted Verilog modules. BFM operation is controlled via a sequence of Verilog tasks contained in a Verilog-syntax text file. The API for the Verilog tasks is described in the AXI BFM User Guide.

The AXI BFM can be used to verify connectivity and basic functionality of AXI masters and AXI slaves with the custom RTL design flow. The AXI BFM provides example test benches and tests that demonstrate the abilities of AXI3, AXI4, AXI4-Lite and AXI4-Stream Master/Slave BFM pair. These examples can be used as a starting point to create tests for custom RTL design with AXI3, AXI4, AXI4-Lite and AXI4-Stream interface. The examples can be accessed from CORE Generator or standalone web download.

The AXI BFM can also be used for embedded designs using Xilinx Platform Studio (XPS). The AXI BFM is available as part of the CIP wizard to create an AXI-based IP with AXI BFM solution. The AXI BFM is also provided as separate pcores that can be accessed from the XPS IP catalog.

There are no evaluation licenses for AXI BFM IP.

**Key Features & Benefits**

- Supports all protocol data widths and address widths, transfer types and responses
- Transaction level protocol checking (burst type, length, size, lock type, cache type)
- Behavioral Verilog Syntax
- Verilog Task-based API
- Delivered in ISE, enabled by a Xilinx-generated license
- Verilog and VHDL example designs and test benches delivered standalone or through CORE Generator for RTL design
- Integrated with XPS as a pcore or as an option with CIP wizard
- Supported Simulators: Aldec Riviera-PRO, Cadence Incisive Enterprise Simulator, ISE Simulator, Mentor Graphics ModelSim and Synopsys VCS

I hope this helps.